# At which temperature does carbon monoxide explode?

Tags: explosives

I had doubt whether carbon monoxide explodes or not. I checked out this resource and found out that carbon monoxide explodes when heated. But they didn't mention the temperature at which it explodes. So my question is that at which temperature does carbon monoxide explode and also at which pressure ?

Thanks in advance!